# HTTP PUT Request: Passing Parameters with File

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post, put

After numerous various tests with uploading files throught HTTP POST Request, it looks that HTTP PUT Requests are the most suitable for very large files +1GB upload.

The below listed simple code I have tested for HTTP PUT file upload request works well:

JavaScript:

```
var req = createRequest();
req.open("PUT", "PHP/filePutLoad.php");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
req.onload = function (event)
{
    console.log(event.target.responseText);
}
req.send(aUploadedFile.file_object);
```

PHP:

```
include 'ChromePhp.php';
require_once 'mysqlConnect.php';

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

ChromePHP::log( '$_PUT :' . print_r($_PUT));

/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
$fp = fopen("myputfile.ext", "w");

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time and write to the file */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
    fwrite($fp, $data);

/* Close the streams */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
```

However, I have difficulties delivering arguments and variables with the file being uploaded from JavaScript to PHP. For example, I need to deliver upload target folder, where the new data needs to be stored, ID of the uploader, etc..

- **Is there a way to combine HTTP PUT Request with HTTP POST to submit arguments?**
- **What are my options if I wish to deliver parameters from JavaScript to PHP along HTTP PUT file upload?**

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried simply adding parameters in exactly the same way as you would with a POST?  What "difficulties" exactly have you had?

Comment: Must it be POST? req.open("PUT", "PHP/filePutLoad.php" + args);

Comment: @Pointy: yes I tried to create the identical parameter submission as with POST request. What happened was, that on the server, I received a file that combined the file I was uploading with the parameters I uploaded. In other words, parameters were merged with the uploaded file on the server.

Comment: @CJ: To be honest, I did not try the GET Request parameter sending. I think, it is worth of try, although I would prefer using post for security reasons. I will send users ID to the server, then the folder where I will upload the data, and I do not wish users to modify this info.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori well that's what happens when you POST a file & parameters too.  The parameters and the file are combined in a single document with MIME separators between them.

Comment: @Pointy: good, so apparently, this is not the way to go, if I wish to upload 1+ GB file with couple of parameters. How to then deliver a set of parameters together with HTTP PUT Request?

Comment: @CJ: I've just did one experiment, and tried to pass parameters through URI. On the server, I can read them from @_GET, so it looks as one possibility. Ideally, however, i would like to pass parameters through POST. If there is any solution, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

using PUT also, it works when you append the parameters in the query string. I'm also looking for another way for this. Although, this is a workaround I'm using currently

curl -X PUT "http://www.my-service.com/myservice?param1=val1" --data @file.txt